# java.lang.AssertionError Trying to test whether an INSERT statement executes successfully

Tags: java, android-studio, junit, android-room, assert

I am trying to set up a test for a Room Database INSERT statement.  I create a test entity and call the dao.insert.  I then created a list of the type said entity and set it equal to The DAO function getALL().  My assert is: assert termsList.contains(testTerm).  When I debug the test method I confirmed that the testTerm was inserted and that the list does in fact contain the testTerm yet I keep getting test failure with a Java.lang.AssertionError.

I am relatively new to Junit and testing, any help would be appreciated.

Here is my test class and code:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SmallTest
public class TermDaoTest {
    private TermDAO termDao;
    private FullDatabase database;

    @Before
    public void createDb(){
        Context context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
        database = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, FullDatabase.class).allowMainThreadQueries().build();
        termDao = database.termDao();
    }

    @After
    public void closeDb() throws IOException {
        database.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void insertTermTest()throws Exception {
        TermEntity testTerm = new TermEntity();
        testTerm.setTermID(1);
        testTerm.setTermName("term1");
        termDao.insert(testTerm);
        List<TermEntity> termsList = termDao.getAllTerms();
        assert termsList.contains(testTerm);

    }

}
```

[Here is the error message I recieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0s4S.png)

[Here is the debugger open showing that the termsList does in fact contain the testTerm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PamZ4.png)

Comment: you need to override "equals" method in TermEntity. testTerm object and testTerm in termsList are infact different. Their IDs and names are the same but on object-level they are different. Either override  equals or compare the ids and names manually like in the  @lazylead answer

Comment: Welcome to SO. Add your error messages to message body, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with android, but in Java SE 8 it may look like as:

```java
assert termsList.stream().anyMatch(
   e -> e.getTermID() == 1 && "term1".equals(e.getTermName())
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This works and the test passed as expected although I am not sure why.  Could you elaborate on what your code is doing here?

Comment: 1.  `assert` receive boolean value;
2. `termsList` is a Collection, thus, by using `stream` you can walk through all elements;
3. `anyMatch` is a terminal operation for stream (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) which returns `true` if some condition passed for 1 element within the collection.